# Is get_posts() more efficient than The Loop?

Tags: loop, get-posts

In `category.php`, I want to get list of posts in that category.

I found two ways: using `get_posts($args)` and `The Loop`.

**get_posts()** way

```
$args = array (
  "category" => ID );
$posts = get_posts($args);
// then use foreach to loop the $posts
```

**The Loop** way

```
<?php if (have_posts() ): ?>
  <?php while (have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    ...
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**So which one more efficient?**

From what I searched, `get_posts()` is for custom template while `The Loop` is used inside the template that follows Wordpress naming convention.

I prefer `get_posts()` but if there's a big overhead compared to The Loop, I should re-think it again.

Comment: So you are talking about secondary `WP_Query()` queries (i.e. not main queries)? ps: `get_posts()` is a `WP_Query()` wrapper.

Comment: Yes, is using only secondary `wp_query` significantly slower or negligible? Because I don't like `The Loop` syntax.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are trying to fetch, but I don't think this matters very much for few items. Do you need to use template tags or do you only need the posts ids? What kind of query arguments are you using? There might be some overhead with `the_post()`. But benchmarking it on your setup might give you the real performance difference. So I think you need to narrow down your question, to get some specific answers.

Comment: ps: but don't use additional secondary queries if you can use the main query or modify it via the `pre_get_posts` action.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. I do need the tags like `get_post_title()` or `get_post_content()`. So, if I can use **main query**, try not to use secondary query?

Comment: Out of curiosity: *why* do you prefer a `get_posts()` loop via `foreach`, rather than a standard `WP_Query()` loop via `while`? Also: you can use post template tags in a `get_posts()` loop via `foreach`, using `setup_postdata()`.

Comment: @ChipBennett using `get_posts($args)` gives me clear control like ordering by date or ascending.

Comment: You have that same exact control with the main loop, or with a new loop using `WP_Query()`.

Comment: @ChipBennett Yeah I saw the explanation in the Answer below. I didn't know that we can pass arguments to The Loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When WordPress include the `category.php` (just like any other template) the main query (i.e.  the query triggered by the url) is **already** ran: it means that a query on database was already fired and this is the reason why in a template you can run the Loop without calling a query.

If you call `get_posts` you ran *another* query to database, that is **completely unnecessary** once is identical to the one already ran by WordPress.

Also note, that `get_posts` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query` so the difference from using the Loop and using the `foreach` syntax, does not regard the query itself, but the way you use the result of the query.

If you prefer `foreach` over `while` (the Loop is just a `while` loop) you can use it also calling directly `WP_Query`:

```
$q = new WP_Query( $args ); // or $q = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
  // here your code e.g.
  $title = $post->title;
  $content = $post->content;
}
```

So why *normally* people use the Loop instead of this kind of loop? for 2 reason, at least:

1. Setup of global `$post` object. When you call `the_post()` inside the Loop, that function globalize the variable `$post` containing the current post object. A lot of core functions and plugins rely on that variale, so often is important to setup. However, it can be set up also using a foreach loop, using `setup_postdata` function, the previous code becomes:

   ```
   global $post;
   foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
     setup_postdata($post);
     // here your code e.g.
     $title = $post->title;
     $content = $post->content;
   }
   ```
2. Second reason regards template tags, over the direct access to post object properties: when you call `the_title` or `the_content` (or other template tags) filters are fired before output the property, and if you don't call them, the output can be not the one you expect, again this can be done *manually* in our foreach loop:

   ```
   $q = new WP_Query( $args );
   global $post;
   foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
     setup_postdata($post);
     // here your code e.g.
     $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->title);
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->content);
   }
   ```

Last code block, can be considered *almost* identical to the Loop.

I said *almost* because there's another thing that differe: 2 action hooks, `loop_start` and `loop_end`, fired by the Loop. Some plugins can use them, so for better compatibility you should do something like:

```
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

global $post;
do_action_ref_array('loop_start', array(&$q));
foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  // here your code e.g.
  $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->title);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->content);
}
do_action_ref_array('loop_end', array(&$q));
```

As already said, this is better used for custom loops, but regarding the main query, calling another `WP_Query` is bad for performance and unnecessary. However, the *main* query is just a `WP_Query` instance, saved in the global variable `$wp_query`, so if in your template you do something like:

```
global $wp_query, $post;
do_action_ref_array('loop_start', array(&$wp_query));
foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  // here your code e.g.
  $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->title);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->content);
}
do_action_ref_array('loop_end', array(&$wp_query));
```

you are doing something very similar (pratically identical) to the Loop, just quite more verbose, but if you just hate `while` loops...

In conclusion, regarding main query, for compatibility reasons is advisable (but not mandatory) use the Loop: if you don't trigger anction and filter hooks there are chance that if you install any plugins some of them will not work...

But for custom loops, sometimes, you don't need (or you don't want) to trigger action and filter hooks, and the `foreach` syntax can be preferable in that cases.

Comment: Thanks, it does clear up a lot of Wordpress thing for me. Cheers!